# Procedure or Function expects parameter which was not supplied even though it is supplied

Tags: stored-procedures

Hello i cannot wrap my head around why i get the error saying that this SP expects @id which was not given when it is quite clearly given. this is how the code looks

```
public Task<bool> InsertMessage(Message msg)
        {
            return CallDatabase(async (connection) =>
            {
                var affectedows = await connection.ExecuteAsync(
                    "messages_insert",
                    new
                    {
                        msg.Id,
                        msg.Group,
                        msg.GroupUserId,
                        msg.userId,
                        msg.StartTime,
                        msg.FinishTime
                    },
                    commandTimeout: 3600,
                    commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure
                    );
                return affectedows == 1;
            });
        }
```

And here is the SP in the db

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[messages_insert]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[messages_insert]';
        DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[messages_insert];
    END

    GO

PRINT 'CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[messages_insert]';
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[messages_insert]
        @id BIGINT,                                 -
        @group INT,                                 
        @group_user_id VARCHAR(100),                    
        @user_id VARCHAR(100),                              
        @start_time DATETIME,                               
        @finish_time DATETIME                              
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO messages(id, group, group_user_id, user_id, start_time, finish_time)
    VALUES(@id, @group, @group_user_id, @user_id, @start_time, @finish_time);
END
GO
```

I really cant see were i am going wrong and the stack trace really says nothing

```
 Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Procedure or function 'messages_insert' expects parameter '@id', which was not supplied.
```

Comment: This isn't a SQL issue.   The issue is in the code calling the procedure.   Please tag appropriately  (I don't recognize the language).

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that msg.Id is not null when calling the stored procedure.